# Integration formula which is based on Integration by cancellation

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\int e^x \left( f(x) + (-1)^{n-1} f^n(x) \right) dx
$$

I think I discovered a formula for this integral where $f^n(x)$ is the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$.

The answer is in terms of $f(x)$ and it includes all of its derivatives up to the $(n-1)$th derivative

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such a result does exist. To get that what you have to do is, add and subtract $f'(x), f^{\prime\prime}(x), \ldots$ upto $f^{n}(x)$ to the $f(x)+(-1)^{n-1}f^{n}(x)$ term. Then group positive and negative signed terms together and observe that the negative terms are derivative of positive terms. Then a simple by parts operation would solve the question.